# printing columns and total wtih specific layout

Tags: java, mysql, printing, jtable, product

I am using netbeans plus a database(MYSQL)for this java Program. In JTable shows the following columns--- product name, Price, Stock available, total sold.All I want in my program is that when I click make sale or say a print button it should print the names of product separated by commas plus the total price of selected rows..In addition to this function, it should also decrement stock available by 1 and increment total sale by 1 to the database.

[1]: see image at https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q5to1.jpg

Comment: And the problem you're having is...?

Comment: the text field is showing only the product which I just selected even I am multi selecting by holding the ctrl key

Comment: After that comment, I think you should consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: I've linked the I image..please check if you can do something.

Answer (score 0):

Simply duplicate the first table.  When a user selects an item from the first table add it it the second table.

As for the database question, you'd have to supply more information about your database before anybody would have a chance to answer it...

[image]

Comment: yes, I think this is a nice option.so instead of printing that table I will command to print this table.Very nice idea. Thanks